# How to update harmonized_system_code and country of origin of a product variant using graphql in shopify

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

```
{
  productVariant(id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/1111111") {
    id
    sku
    inventoryItem {
      countryCodeOfOrigin
      harmonizedSystemCode
    }
  }
}
```

With the above code, I can get the data countryCodeOfOrigin and harmonizedSystemCode. But the issue is mutation is not updating this data. Please let me know about it if anyone has knowledge regarding this

Comment: Did you try the mutation for Inventory Items? The mutation seems to contain all the fields you're interested in. https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/mutations/inventoryItemUpdate